# MAC address not correct in Xamarin as compared to Cocoa API

Tags: c#, xamarin, cocoa, xamarin.mac

I am having an issue while extracting the MAC address of macOS device.

When I use Objective-C or Swift code I get a different result (though the first one is the actual MAC address).
But when I use Xamarin/C# code I get a different result.

But when I check for the actual MAC address in System Preferences I get what is extracted from the Obj-C code.

The output of both are attached here:

Is there any way to filter out to get the value given by the Cocoa API or use the Cocoa API in Xamarin project?

**Objective-C code, here you see the first printed value is the MAC address.**

[image]

**Xamarin / C# code, here 3rd in the list is the MAC address.**

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for as all those are valid NICs, "operational up" NICs on macOS will include not "just" Internet-based active nics, but also local tunnels, thunderbolt, bluetooth, firewire, etc... connections. You can not expect the first one returned to always be the one that you need.

Comment: @SushiHangover: I've a legacy client that used the above Obj-c code to send MAC address. So from the new client I should send the same MAC address. So how do I know which one is the right one to send?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `F0:18:98` is assigned to Apple, Inc. so it might be an ethernet, wifi|airport, ... NIC/port.

Lookup the actual assigned name, does it start with `en`?

i.e. Is it always `en0` via `SCNetworkInterface` in the SystemConfiguration framework? If so, Linq filter your Mono `NetInterface` list based on the `Name` property.